# Probability of visiting $4$ cities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> On her vacations Veena visits four cities $(A, B, C\ \text{and}\ D)$ in a random
>   order.
>
> What is the probability that she visits
>
> (i) $A$ before $B$?
>
> (ii) $A$ before $B$ and $B$ before $C$?
>
> (iii) $A$ first and $B$ last?
>
> (iv) $A$ either first or second?
>
> (v) $A$ just before $B$?

The number of ways Veena can visit four cities is $4!=24$

$S = \{ABCD, ABDC, ACBD, ACDB, ADBC, ADCB\\
BACD, BADC, BDAC, BDCA, BCAD, BCDA\\
CABD, CADB, CBDA, CBAD, CDAB, CDBA\\
DABC, DACB, DBCA, DBAC, DCAB, DCBA\}$

I want to know if their is an easier way than writing all these $24$ possibilities .

I know their might be some permutation and combination way to solve it easily but I can't figure it out.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: There is a really quick and simple way to answer the first question.  I have posted it below and left the other questions alone. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with part $(i)$ (the other parts will use the same idea):

If Veena is to visit $A$ before she visits $B$, then we are looking to count the number of strings using $A,B,C,D$, where $A$ precedes $B$. Such strings could have the form

$$AB__$$
$$A_B_$$
$$A__B$$
$$_AB_$$
$$_A_B$$
$$__AB$$

We didn't actually need to list these; we could have simply recognized that there are 3 possible positions for $A$ (any but the last), and that if $A$ is in position $i$ ($i = 1,2,3$), then there are $4-i$ possible positions for $B$. Therefore the number of such strings *of this general form* is $\sum_{i=1}^3(4-i) = 3+2+1 = 6$, which agrees with the list above.

Now all we have to do is place $C$ and $D$, and there are no restrictions on how we may do this. There are two ways to place $C$ and $D$ in the empty spaces in each string listed above, therefore we get a total of $2\cdot6 = 12$ unique strings where $A$ precedes $B$.

Thus the probability that Veena visits $A$ before she visits $B$ is
$$\frac{\text{# of strings where $A$ precedes $B$}}{\text{total number of strings}} = \frac{12}{4!} = \frac{1}{2}$$

For parts $(ii)$ - $(v)$, the same general method is employed, we are just putting different restrictions on the particular types of strings we are looking for.

Comment: I should add that this isn't quite the quickest way to do part $(i)$ in particular; but it does present a general method that will produce a solution for each of parts $(i)$ - $(v)$. Anyway I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: One can give a much simpler answer, at least for the first question. (The others are more involved than the first, though.) See my answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy see my comment just above yours.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, which is more likely, A before B or B before A? Keep in mind one of these two has to occur. So P(A before B)+P(B before A)=1. Would it make sense for one of these to have a higher probability than the other?

For the second one, we know she visits and and then B and then C. The only question is, where does D fit in? How many places can you put D in between or outside ABC?visualize this as _A_B_C_. The D has to go into one of those open slots. How many slots are there?

For the third, if A is first and B is last, how many ways can we fill in the middle? We can visualize this as A_ _B. How many ways can I put C and D in the two open slots?

For the fourth, we can use similar reasoning to the first. Is it more likely for A to be (first or second) or (third or fourth)? But one of the two has to happen. What does that tell you about the probability?

For the last one, if A is just before B, then we can think of AB as a single object. Then it's how many ways can we visit three cities?(well... Two cities and one double city) then divide by 24. This one is $\frac{3!}{4!}=\frac{1}4$ as you stated in a comment.

Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I really liked your explanation for number 1.  +1

Comment: @:SE318: For the third and fourth one i think u mean $3!/24=1/4$ . For the $1$st and $2$nd ways ,i don't understand .

Comment: @R K I expanded on my hints a little bit. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> (i) A before B?

$50\%$ she'll visit $A$ before $B$ and $50\%$ she'll visit $A$ after $B$, so the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

> (ii) A before B and B before C?

Arrange $ABC$ by that order, and then stick $D$ anywhere. There are $4$ ways to do it:

- $ABCD$
- $ABDC$
- $ADBC$
- $DABC$

Hence the probability is $\frac{4}{24}=\frac{1}{6}$.

---

> (iii) A first and B last?

Arrange $A$ first and $B$ last, and then stick $C$ and $D$ between them. There are $2$ ways to do it:

- $ACDB$
- $ADCB$

Hence the probability is $\frac{2}{24}=\frac{1}{12}$.

---

> (iv) A either first or second?

$A$ can be located in either one of $4$ places, with equal probability for each one of them.

Hence the probability is $\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

> (v) A just before B?

This description is rather tricky.

One might interpret it as if $A$ **has to** come before $B$.

I believe that the actual meaning is that $A$ **is allowed to** come only before $B$.

There are $2$ combinations in which $A$ comes only before $B$:

- $CDAB$
- $DCAB$

And there are $6$ more combinations in which $A$ doesn't come before any letter:

- $BCDA$
- $BDCA$
- $CBDA$
- $CDBA$
- $DBCA$
- $DCBA$

Hence the probability is $\frac{2+6}{24}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: This is a matter of interpretation, of course, but I think the last part is intended to mean that you have AB occurring somewhere in the sequence, which would give 6 possibilities.

Comment: @user84413: But then $A$ would possibly also be before some other letter. I agree though, it is a matter of interpretation.

Comment: I am interpreting "just before" as meaning "immediately before", but it could also mean "only before", as you say.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that she visits A before B must be $1$ minus the probability that she visits B before A.

Suppose we find the probability that she visits A before B.

Then we rename the cities, so the one we called A we now call B and vice-versa. What is *then* the probability that she visits A before B?  It's the same math problem, so the probability must be the same number.  But now it's the probability that she visits the city we initially called B before she visits the city we initially called A.

Therefore the probability that she visits A before B must be the same as the probability that she visits B before A, and the sum of those two (equal) numbers must be $1$.  Hence that probability is $1/2$.

That is an argument from symmetry.